# Change Colour on Chapter/Section headings {Lyx}

Tags: color, lyx

I am using Lyx and Layout report for my thesis.
I would like to change the colour of chapters sections and subsections (only the headings) from black to blue.

I attach a screenshot in order to understand what colours i am trying to achieve only on headings (Chapter /section  and subsection )

[image]

Also is it possible to change the colour of table of contents to blue ? (again only the heading)

Comment: See also [sectioning - Giving headlines a background color spanning across the entire typearea - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/giving-headlines-a-background-color-spanning-across-the-entire-typearea) for changing the background color, or  [sectioning - LaTex - Change color of section - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310586/latex-change-color-of-section#comments-310587) for changing one section only

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the package [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) to do change the headings, and [`xcolor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) to get the colour definitions.

For example, add to your preamble (Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble) the following:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{blue}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{cyan}}  % sets colour of sections
```

[image]

You can use colours predefined in [`xcolor` (see manual)](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xcolor), or define your own, e.g.

```
\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,1}
```

Put such definitions in the preamble as well.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this and ill come back if i have problems by using xcolor :)

Comment: @ALdaperan I forgot to mention that the TOC heading is just an unnumbered chapter, so that will also be influenced by `\chapterfont{\color{blue}}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. does this also work with chapters in book style? I have changed sections with ease but it did not work for chapters...

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Yes, it does. Do you use *Book (Standard Class)*?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. this is in my preamble: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twosided,openright]{book}`

Comment: That's the one. `\documentclass{book}\usepackage{xcolor}\usepackage{sectsty}\chapterfont{\color{blue}} \begin{document}\chapter{A}\end{document}` works fine, so there has to be something else messing things up it doesn't work for you. If you can't figure it out, create an MWE and ask a new question about it. (`twoside` - not `twosided` - and `openright` are default for `book`, so you don't really need to specify them.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. does it make any difference, if I am using a bidi package?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent No idea, never used any such packages, but just try, and you'll find out.

Comment: how can I do the same thing in **theorem**, **lemma**, **definition**. etc.. many thanks.

Comment: @user35528 I don't know, I suggest you post a new question :)

Answer (score 9):

This thread seems to be closed for quite a while, but as I found it right after searching for a solution some minutes ago, I just thought I could add the solution I found for solving the problem.

For all those of you who use KOMA Script Classes: its just adding one line if you are going for changing the color of all headlines during your document; be it chapters, sections, subsections and what not alltogether.

By adding

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
```

you change all the headlines to the standard font you are using during your document, and by replacing `\normalcolor` by anything you whish you change the color for all headlines. It workes for selfdefined colors and as the other solution it applies for the `\tableofcontents`, too.

Example

```
\definecolor{schrift}{RGB}{0,73,114}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color{schrift}\bfseries}
```

Here we have an example of code in which I used that method

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cancel, caption, mathtools, subcaption, amsthm}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[margin={0.08\paperwidth,0.10\paperheight}, heightrounded]{geometry}

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 6pt

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.6em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{2}{4.0em}{3.6em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.4em}{4.5em}}
\makeatother

\fboxrule0pt

\definecolor{rahmen}{RGB}{0,73,114}
\definecolor{grund}{RGB}{238,241,251}          
\definecolor{schrift}{RGB}{0,73,114}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={color=rahmen,bf}}

\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{OML}{cmbr}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{normal}{OMS}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf} {OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\color{schrift}\bfseries}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={color=schrift,bf}}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\hfuzz 100pt
\hbadness 10000

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace *{-\baselineskip }}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Zentralkraftbewegungen}
\section{Erhaltungsgr\"oßen der Zentralkraftbewegung}
\subsection{Der Lenz-Runge Vektor}

\begin{equation}
    \Lambda =   \frac{1}{m\alpha} \Big( \mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{L} \Big) - \mathbf{e}_r
\end{equation}

Zu zeigen:

\begin{equation*}
    \Lambda = \mathrm{~const.} \leftrightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} ~\Lambda = 0
\end{equation*}

Zur Diskussion des Problems sind Zylinderkoodinaten mit konstanter Höhe erforderlich. Wähle also als Höhe $z=0$. Der Nabla-Operator in Zylinderkoordinaten hat die Form

\begin{equation}
    \boldsymbol\nabla   = \mathbf{e}_r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \mathbf{e}_{\varphi} \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} + \mathbf{e}_z \frac{\partial}{\partial z} 
\end{equation}

Das Keplerpotential hat die Form

\begin{equation}
    V = -\frac{\alpha}{r}
\end{equation}

\begin{proof}[Beweis für den Lenz-Runge Vektor als Erhaltungsgröße des Keplerproblems]
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \Lambda      &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \bigg\{ \frac{1}{m\alpha} \Big(\mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{L} \Big) \bigg\} - \dot{\mathbf{e}}_r \\
                                                &= \frac{1}{m\alpha} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \bigg\{ \mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{L} \bigg\} - \dot{\mathbf{e}}_r \\
                                                &= \frac{1}{m\alpha} \bigg\{ \dot{\mathbf{p}} \times \mathbf{L} + \cancel{\mathbf{p} \times \dot{\mathbf{L}}} \bigg\} - \dot{\mathbf{e}}_r 
\end{align*}

\noindent\fcolorbox{rahmen}{grund}{\parbox{\linewidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}{%
Für die Kraft $\mathbf{F}$ folgt aus der Konservativität und dem Keplerpotential

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{F}  = -\boldsymbol\nabla V 
                = - \bigg[\Big( \mathbf{e}_r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \mathbf{e}_{\varphi} \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} + \mathrm{e}_z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \Big) \cdot \Big(-\frac{\alpha}{r} \Big) \bigg] 
                = -\mathbf{e}_r \frac{\alpha}{r^2}
\end{equation}
}}

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \Lambda      &= \frac{1}{m\alpha} \bigg\{ \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{L} \bigg\} - \dot{\mathbf{e}}_r \\
                                                &= -\frac{1}{mr^2} \bigg\{ \mathbf{e}_r \times \mathbf{L} \bigg\} - \dot{\mathbf{e}}_r \\
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the output

[image: page one of two of that document]

Comment: If you just want to change the color of the chapter, section, ..., for your KOMA script, then it is also possible to use:
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{your_color}}
This will only change the color and leave everything else (bold, italics, ...) untouched.