# LaTex - Change color of section

Tags: sectioning, color

I want to change the color of a single section, and that color must not be changed in Table of Contents.

```
\subsubsection{{\color{red} Embedded Design}}
```

This is the code I used, but the color will automatically changed in Content. Please Help.

Best Regards.

Comment: You're asking just for the section title, right? Not the whole section

Comment: See also (mostly) [color - Change Colour on Chapter/Section headings {Lyx} - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75667/change-colour-on-chapter-section-headings-lyx)  for changing color of every section.

Answer (score 4):

```
\subsubsection[Embedded Design]{{\color{red} Embedded Design}}
```

The part in the square brackets, defines the optional title of a *section that will be shown in the `toc`

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't do it, but ... you asked for it.

[image: harisSectionColored]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Wombat}
{\color{blue!50!black}
\section{Capybara}
}
\section{Mara}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code in preamble to change color of links according to your choice.Use black instead of red if you want links in `toc` to appear black.

```
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
linkcolor={red!100!black},
citecolor={blue!100!black},
urlcolor={green!100!black}}
```