# No space anymore between section heading and numbering

Tags: sectioning, color

I'm new to LaTeX. I tried to change the color of my chapter and section headings and the easiest way I found was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75667/change-colour-on-chapter-section-headings-lyx) here with

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{blue}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{cyan}}  % sets colour of sections
```

It works fine, but before

```
\chapter{Materials and Methods}
\section{Study Site}
```

created

**2 Materials and Methods**

**2.1 Study Site**.

Now it is

**2Materials and Methods**    <- Missing space

**2.1 Study Site**.

Does someone know how to correct this problem or knows a better way to change the colors of all chapters and sections? If there is more code required let me know.

Thank you all ahead!

My short example: 
(I have kept all packages whose purpose is unknown to me)

```
\documentclass[%
english,ngerman,%
BCOR=6mm,cdgeometry=no,%
DIV=13,cdfont=true
]{tudscrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Packages for text: 
\usepackage{sectsty} % to change the headings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\chapterfont{\color{TUDblue}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{TUDblue2}}  % sets colour of sections

\ifpdftex{
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
}{
\usepackage{fontspec}
}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

% Colors: 
\definecolor{TUDblue}{RGB}{0,48,94}
\definecolor{TUDblue2}{RGB}{0,106,179}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % Here is still space

\chapter{Introduction} % Here not anymore
\section{Experimental design}
\subsection{What am I doing?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a minimal self contained document that show the problem that others can copy and test as is. Here for example we don't know which document class you are using. Sectsty does not work with all classes

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I have a  strong suspect that you are using a KoMa class but that's an information we need, otherwise there is no way we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using a documentclass provided by the Technical University of Darmstadt => TUD. As far as I remember, those documentclasses are based on KOMA-script.

Instead of installing those classes, I changed the documentclass to scrreprt.

KOMA-script easily allows to change the color of headings, but doesn't work well with sectsty. You get the whole manual by typing `texdoc scrguien` on the command line.

That said, I just added two lines to your code and commented out some other lines:

```
\documentclass[%
english,ngerman,%
BCOR=6mm,cdgeometry=no,%
DIV=13,%cdfont=true
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Packages for text: 
%\usepackage{sectsty} % to change the headings
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\chapterfont{\color{TUDblue}}  % sets colour of chapters
%\sectionfont{\color{TUDblue2}}  % sets colour of sections

\ifpdftex{
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
}{
\usepackage{fontspec}
}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

%%%% Color with KOMAscript in sections

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{blue}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{cyan}}

% Colors: 
%\definecolor{TUDblue}{RGB}{0,48,94}
%\definecolor{TUDblue2}{RGB}{0,106,179}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % Here is still space

\chapter{Introduction} % Here not anymore
\section{Experimental design}
\subsection{What am I doing?}

\end{document}
```

Please adapt the colors, I had to swap TUD-colors to the available colors on my system:

[image: pic of rendered code]