# Section title coloring code makes Table of content numbered

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, numbering

I was looking for a way to have a colorbox as background of section titles. The following answer that I got [on this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/giving-headlines-a-background-color-spanning-across-the-entire-typearea) was succesful in doing just that. But it has a side effect that is rather unpleasant, which is to put a number in front on the Table of Contents that corresponds to the section it is now in.

For exemple, if I put my table of contents in the Section 3, it will show correctly the list of all section, but "Table of content" is preceded by a "3".

If I put it in the Section 4, then it will be preceded by a "4"

I think that my program has to do with the way the printing of the colored section title was programmed, but since I am a total beginner, I have a hard time to figure how I could change that and not lose the formatting it provides

Here is the code I used.

Thanks a lot

```
    %This is for a section, but you can extend it easily for subsections with a similar scheme:

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\sffamily\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\thesection\ #1}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\section{This is the title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
%If you want white on colored text, just modify the \colorsection command, for example as

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\color{white}\thesection\ #1}}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean, but removing `\thesection` from `\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%....` solves the problem?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Well, it fixes and breaks it. If I take off `\thesection`, then I don't have any numbering in front of my sections. The Table of contents is now okay (It's only written "Table of contents" and no more "3 Table of contents").

But then, I don't have either any numbering for my sections. "1 Introduction" is now "Introduction", etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the current definition, the `\thesection` counter will be used both for both numbered and unnumbered sections, which is clearly unwanted. Using the `numberless` key, you can provide a definition for unnumbered sections adding the colored background but without the numbering (notice also the use of the `explicit` option for `titlesec`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\sffamily\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\strut\thesection~#1\strut}}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\sffamily\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\strut#1\strut}}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Numbered section}
\lipsum[4]
\section*{Unnumbered section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can see that it works well in your exemple. But I can't get it to work here. I get multiple error messages including this one: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \ttlf@section \titleformat`

I added the [explicit] option to the titlesec package, but it only made that the `\titleformat{name=\section}[block]` line results in an error.

Comment: @LeVulgarisateur please notice that instead of `\usepackage{titlesec}` you must now use `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`.

Comment: @LeVulgarisateur If my previous comment still doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question and add a simple complete document (like the one in my answer) producing the mentioned error.

Comment: I had used the [explicit] option... the problem is that I called twice the titlesec package and didn't notice it. Shame on me! Everything works fine now.

Comment: @LeVulgarisateur Ah, OK, then. Glad to see it's working now!

Comment: A note for future readers: adding the `[explicit]` option to the `\usepackage` temporarily broke my part headings until I realised that I needed to add a `{#1}` to my `\titleformat{\part}` section.  Yes, I am a n00b.