# Background fill for section title

Tags: highlighting

I am trying to highlight background for entire section heading using

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{charter}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=.3in, vmargin=0.1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{array}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{\colorbox{gray}}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0em}{0.5em}{0.25em}
\begin{document}
\section{Lobo}
(Type your content here.)
\end{document}
```

but it only highlights the text. How do I highlight the entire line ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In case the liked question does not help you, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40051/36296 gives

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{charter}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=.3in, vmargin=0.1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{array}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{\colorsection}[\titlerule]

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{\colorsectionnonumber}[\titlerule]

\titlespacing{\section}{0em}{0.5em}{0.25em}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\thesection\ #1}}}

\newcommand{\colorsectionnonumber}[1]{%
    \colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \section{bla}

    abc

    \section*{Lobo}
    (Type your content here.)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the number in the section title ?

Comment: `\section*{Lobo}`? But that's a new question.

Comment: It is only changing the number to 0

Comment: @SuryaPavanPynda please see the edit.

Comment: It works.. My fault.. Thanks for the help :)