# Nice customised titlepage for every section (scrartcl)

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script, titlesec

I have a relatively simple LaTeX document with a few sections and subsections and everything would be fine, BUT: I would like to have a custom designed titlepage for every section. (btw. MWE at the bottom!) My TOC looks like this:

[image]

Right now, the page with a new section (e.g. 2 A second...) looks like this:

[image]

But I rather would like to have something that stands out! This is my idea, how I would like to see e.g. section 2:

[image]

You find a MWE is below!

My question now is: How can I create these nice looking title pages for my sections? I think there are some possibilities with the `titlesec` package. But I'm not good in trying it myself. Can anybody help me with this? Any help is very much appreciated!

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
11pt,
headsepline,
footsepline,
]
{scrartcl}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}                           
\usepackage{amsmath}                            
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{longtable}                      
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{ulem}                   
\usepackage[version=3,arrows=pgf]{mhchem}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{wasysym}            
\usepackage{rsphrase}                       
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\usepackage{tikz}                           
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bottom=3.5cm}
\geometry{top=3.5cm}
\geometry{left=2.5cm}
\geometry{right=2.5cm}
\usepackage{enumerate}                          
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage[linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{figure}{section}
\@addtoreset{table}{section}
\makeatother 
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic {figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}    

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}   
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  

\sisetup{%
    obeyall,            
    per=frac,               
    decimalsymbol=comma,    
    unitmode=text   
    }

\hbadness=10000
\vbadness=10000
\hyphenpenalty=100000
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\linespread{1.25}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\thispagestyle{empty}

\LARGE
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{center} \LARGE 
\textbf{\LARGE XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\}
\textbf{\LARGE XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\}
\end{center}
\vspace{1.0cm}

\begin{center}
\Large
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
\end{center}
\vspace{1.0cm}

\begin{table}[!h]
\Large
\begin{tabular}{ll}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & \\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX& \\
\end{tabular}
\normalsize
\end{table}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{table}[!b]
\Large
\begin{tabular}{ll}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXh\\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
v & \\
\end{tabular}
\normalsize
\end{table}
\normalsize

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}

\section*{section X}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \\

\large
\paragraph{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\clearpage  
\thispagestyle{empty}

\phantom{oben}
\phantom{oben}
\phantom{oben}
\phantom{oben}
\phantom{oben}
\phantom{oben}
\phantom{oben}
\phantom{oben}
\phantom{oben}

\begin{flushright} \LARGE 
\textbf{\LARGE It will be fine.\\}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{1.0cm}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}

\clearpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\clearpage

\clearpage
\section*{some other hidden chapter}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{A first very nice and fancy looking title}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 

\subsection{subsectionn 1-1}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 

\subsection{subsectionn 1-2}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 

\subsubsection{subsubsection 1-2-1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\section{A second very nice and fancy looking title}

\subsection{subsection 2-1}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

\subsection{subsection 2-2}

\subsubsection{subsubsection 2-2-1}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

\subsubsection{subsubsection 2-2-1}

\subsection{subsection 2-3}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\section{A third very nice and fancy looking title}

\subsection{subsection 3-1}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

\subsection{subsection 3-2}

\subsubsection{subsubsection 3-2-1}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

\subsubsection{subsubsection 3-2-1}

\subsection{subsection 3-3}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is far from minimal. Is it possible to compress it a bit?

Comment: `titlesec` and KOMA is a bad combination

Comment: `geometry` and KOMA isn't a great choice, either. (Not as bad as `titlesec` and KOMA.)

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete. I'm surprised that loading it with `subfig` even works, especially with `caption` added to the mix. Is your file really saved in `ansinew` encoding? Most editors these days use UTF8 by default. (TeXShop does not, but it doesn't use `ansinew` either.) `setspace` and `\linespread` are not fantastic with KOMA either. See the documentation for details of precautions you should take, things you shouldn't expect to work etc. Especially for `titlesec` & `geometry`, but also the other relevant packages you're using.

Comment: @cfr `geometry` is the package of choice with KOMA script if fixed margins are to be defined.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong document class. You are looking for chapters, which `scrartcl` does not provide. Are you looking for `scrreprt` or `scrbook`?

Comment: If i was in your spot, i would stop scavenging old google results for some valuable content and read a recent LaTeX introduction. You code is a mess, not even mentioning using a documentclas that is not supposed to do what you want.

Comment: @Johannes_B Only in the sense that if you must have blah, then using `geometry` is tolerable. It isn't the recommended approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution in which I patched the `\section` command to get the desired formatting. The additional data, i.e. the "Here comes a small text..." part in your example picture is gathered via `\sectionpreamble` right before issuing the `\section` command:

```
\sectionpreamble{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
}
\section{There will be a very long title here that spans lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of lines}
```

The complete code would be:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\thesectionwdmax
\newdimen\sectiontitlewd
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\scalebox{5}{99}}
  \thesectionwdmax\wd0
  \sectiontitlewd\dimexpr\textwidth-\thesectionwdmax-2.25cm\relax
}
\def\section{\par
   \addvspace{4ex}%
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@sec\@ssec}
\def\@sec[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{section}%\@maybeasf%
       \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent\z@
     \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \normalfont
     \setbox0=\vbox{\parbox{\sectiontitlewd}{\noindent\huge#2}}
     \sectfont
     \raisebox{-1em}{\parbox[c]{\thesectionwdmax}{\noindent\null\hfill\scalebox{5}{\thesection}}}
     \hspace{.25cm}
     \raisebox{1em}{\parbox[t][\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax]{1em}{\leaders\vrule\vfill}}
     \hspace{1cm}
     \parbox[t]{\sectiontitlewd}{\noindent\huge#2}
     \vfill\printsectionpreamble\vfill
     \sectionmark{}\par}%
     \nobreak
    \@afterheading
    \clearpage}
\def\@ssec#1{%
    {\parindent\z@
     \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \sectfont #1
     \vfill\printsectionpreamble\vfill
     \sectionmark{}\par}%
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading
    \clearpage}
\def\printsectionpreamble{%
  \ifx\currentsecpreamble\empty\else
    \colorbox{pink}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\normalfont\normalsize\currentsecpreamble}}\fi
  \let\currentsecpreamble\empty}
\def\sectionpreamble#1{\gdef\currentsecpreamble{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\sectionpreamble{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
}
\section{There will be a very long title here that spans lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of lines}
%...
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: WOW thats almost it! Two small things though: 1) how can I confine the design of the seperate titlepages to only e.g. section 2 and 3 (even, if I have 5+ sections) 2) Can I set the title left aligned?

Comment: @AndreH -- 1) just define a distinct macro, say `\AndreHsection` `\mysection` or `\titlepagedsection` or whatever instead of redefining `\section` (i.e. see the line `\def\section...`); 2) the title is left aligned. Beeing Completely left it will clip with the section number and the vertical line. You can reduce the space between the line and the title tho.

Comment: You should not patch `\section`. Simply [redefine `\sectionlinesformat`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269013/9057).

Comment: This is it, i managed to get all titlepages right :-) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion redefining the KOMA-Script command `\sectionlinesformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newdimen\thesectionwdmax
\newdimen\sectiontitlewd
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{{\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{section}\scalebox{2}{99}}}%
  \thesectionwdmax\wd0%
  \sectiontitlewd\dimexpr\textwidth-\thesectionwdmax-.75cm-1pt\relax
}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{\protect\scalebox{2}{\thesection}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\ifstr{#3}{}
      {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}
      {%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{.25cm}\vrule width 1pt\hspace{.5cm}}l@{}}
        \parbox{\thesectionwdmax}{\centering#3}%
        &%
        {\parbox{\sectiontitlewd}{\raggedright#4}}%
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
    }
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}%
}

\newcommand\sectionpreamble[1]{{%
  \vfill
  \setlength\fboxsep{2em}%
  \colorbox{lightgray}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
      {\raggedright #1}%
  }%
  \vfill
  \clearpage
}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{There will be a very long title here that spans lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of lines}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A short title}
\lipsum[2]

\clearpage
\section{There will be a very long title here that spans lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of lines}
\sectionpreamble{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[5-6]

\section{Another section}
\lipsum
\addsec{Unnumbered section}
More text ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is also VERY nice! I actually learned a lot from your code. I'm now done with my document, but I will keep this answer also in my bookmarks! Thank you very much! :-)