# Change a \section or \paragraph style in scrbook

Tags: koma-script, paragraphs, titlesec

I am willing to modify either the `\section` or `\paragraph` (sec/par) style in the scrbook (but I'm open to other book environment) in order to obtain:

- no reset counter after new `\chapter` (I have an idea about that)
- a centered sec/par number like in between hooks,  [sec/par number]
- the sec/par name under the number, centered too

Is there a way to do that by simply invoke `\titleformat`, or shall I need a `\renewcommand` or more ? Perhaps a new environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps you should add to the description, because it's not very clear what you'd like to get.

Comment: Don't use `titlesec` with koma-script.

Comment: When it comes to formating koma sectioning layout, you can check out the answers given to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40034/10478) to get an idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for something like

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    counterwithout=chapter
]{section}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}\autodot}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\centering #3\\*#4}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\sectionformat{--~\thesection~--}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[4-5]

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Third Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

But it looks ugly for me:

[image]