# Two-column table of contents, section runs into color bar

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol

I am typesetting a summary of my chemistry semester (in German) and ran into the following problem using

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
```

with the package `multicol`:[image]

I made the color section bars with [Sharpie's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40188).

I am wondering if there is a possibility to (maybe manually, but this is `LaTeX`, so hopefully automatically) adjust the section of `10 Redoxreaktionen` to align with `1 Stöchiometrie`.

I could use the unbalanced version of `multicol`, however I don't think this is pleasing to the eyes. Actually, using the unbalanced environment (with the `*`) doesn't eliminate this problem, because `17 Farben` would still be in the bar of the title of the toc.

Here is the MWE, I doesn't cover every part of the summary, but describes my issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\title{\textbf{GF\,CH: Themen für die mündliche Prüfung}}
\date{Montag, 1.7.2019}
\author{}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{255,127.5,0}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  % Styling of header text is done using key/value options for TikZ nodes. See
  % section 16.4 of the PGF manual for a complete list of options that affect
  % text.
  headings/base/.style = {
    % Zap node seperation, set text width and alignment.
    outer sep = 0pt,
    % Trim off 2/3rd of an em to compensate for the inner xsep which spaces the
    % text nicely away from the left side, but causes the node to hang into the
    % right margin.
    text width = {\textwidth - 0.6666em},
    align = left,
    text = black,
  },
  headings/section/.style = {
    headings/base,
    fill = myorange!50,
    font = \sffamily\large
  },
  headings/subsection/.style = {
    headings/base,
    fill = myorange!25,
    font = \sffamily\large
  }
}

\newcommand{\colorboxedsec}[2]{%
  \tikz{\node[headings/#1]{#2};}}

\setkomafont{section}{\colorboxedsec{section}}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\colorboxedsec{subsection}}




\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols*}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Stöchiometrie}
\section{Die Geometrie von Teilchen}
\section{Zwischenpartikulare Kräfte}
\subsection{van}
\section{Reaktionsgeschwindigkeit} 
\section{Das chemische Gleichgewicht}
\section{Beeinflussung von chemischen Gleichgewichten}
\section{Fällungsreaktionen}
\section{Komplexreaktionen}
\section{S/B-Reaktionen}
\section{Redoxreaktionen} 
\section{Titration}
\section{Der pH-Wert} 
\section{Der (technische) Kalkkreislauf} 
\section{Chiralität}
\section{E/Z-Isomerie}
\section{Mesomerie und Farbe}
\section{Farben}
\section{Sprengstoffe}
\section{Proteine}
\section{Enzyme}
\section{Nervengifte, Rauschgifte}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I realize that this question may not have anything to do with ´multicol´, as the title of the section (Inhaltsverzeichnis) doesn't interfere with the section when used without the TikZ sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `\makeatletter` commands solved my problem:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\title{\textbf{GF\,CH: Themen für die mündliche Prüfung}}
\date{Montag, 1.7.2019}
\author{}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{255,127.5,0}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  % Styling of header text is done using key/value options for TikZ nodes. See
  % section 16.4 of the PGF manual for a complete list of options that affect
  % text.
  headings/base/.style = {
    % Zap node seperation, set text width and alignment.
    outer sep = 0pt,
    % Trim off 2/3rd of an em to compensate for the inner xsep which spaces the
    % text nicely away from the left side, but causes the node to hang into the
    % right margin.
    text width = {\textwidth - 0.6666em},
    align = left,
    text = black,
  },
  headings/section/.style = {
    headings/base,
    fill = myorange!50,
    font = \sffamily\large
  },
  headings/subsection/.style = {
    headings/base,
    fill = myorange!25,
    font = \sffamily\large
  }
}

\newcommand{\colorboxedsec}[2]{%
  \tikz{\node[headings/#1]{#2};}}

\setkomafont{section}{\colorboxedsec{section}}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\colorboxedsec{subsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\section*{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Stöchiometrie}
\section{Die Geometrie von Teilchen}
\section{Zwischenpartikulare Kräfte}
\subsection{van}
\section{Reaktionsgeschwindigkeit} 
\section{Das chemische Gleichgewicht}
\section{Beeinflussung von chemischen Gleichgewichten}
\section{Fällungsreaktionen}
\section{Komplexreaktionen}
\section{S/B-Reaktionen}
\section{Redoxreaktionen} 
\section{Titration}
\section{Der pH-Wert} 
\section{Der (technische) Kalkkreislauf} 
\section{Chiralität}
\section{E/Z-Isomerie}
\section{Mesomerie und Farbe}
\section{Farben}
\section{Sprengstoffe}
\section{Proteine}
\section{Enzyme}
\section{Nervengifte, Rauschgifte}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made the section headings have full textwidth, so if you use \tableofcontents inside multicols it naturally overprints into the right column (most likely the same if if you use \twocolumn instead).

So either you need to make the heading use \columnwidth or you have to redefine \tableofcontents so that it does the call to multicols and keeps the \section*{...} outside of it. Which is what I think you want.