# Why is there a blue rectangle at the top of my TOC?

Tags: titlesec

I am using a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/giving-headlines-a-background-color-spanning-across-the-entire-typearea/40051?noredirect=1#comment1579614_40051) provided by @egreg to put a background around my section titles. However, there is a blue rectangle appearing at the top of the TOC. Does anyone know how to remove this?

A picture of my TOC:

[image]

A working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=18mm, right=18mm,top=18mm,bottom=18mm,includehead=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdfview=FitB,hidelinks]{hyperref}

%Format the section titles/headings
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
    {\Large}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-5mm}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} %removes numbering from sections


\title{A TOC with a blue rectangle}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont
\maketitle
\def\contentsname{\empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Why?}
\subsection{O Why?}


\begin{itemize}
\item I don't know.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Is this rectangle at the top of my TOC?}

The solution is probably very straightforward, but I am just not seeing it.


\section{I'm stumped!}

This is so weird.



\end{document}
```

Comment: well the table of contents starts with `\section{\contentsname}`, `\contentsname` is empty but a `\section{}` will still produce a box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\tableofcontents` issues `\section*{\contentsname}`, so it's not sufficient to say `\def\contentsname{\empty}` and, by the way, it should be

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
```

because `\empty` is *not* empty. What you really want to do is that `\tableofcontents` doesn't issue a `\section` command.

For the `article` class, the simplest way to remove the `\section` command is to do, in the preamble,

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, @egreg. One question: Are you saying that `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}` and `\makeatletter \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}\makeatother` are both doing the same thing, but the latter is preferred to the former?

Comment: @SamY. No. If you want to redefine a tag to produce nothing, use `{}`, not `{\empty}`. But this is *not* sufficient for your purpose, because `\section*{}` still produces a section title (with no title). You need to remove `\section*{\contentsname}` altogether from the code of `\tableofcontents`. I tried to better clarify.

Comment: I understand more now, thank you for clarifying. I am accepting the answer too :)